# Docker mount works only on localhost

Tags: linux, ssl, nginx, docker, .net-core

I want to create mounting with docker. I have dotnet app, where I want to mounting certs folder with self signet ssl certificate. On localhost it works well, but on my VPS (I have root permissions) don't.

My operation system on remote machine:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.6 (jessie)
Release:    8.6
Codename:   jessie
```

Simply docker file in app:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY out .

EXPOSE 5000/tcp 5001/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

My docker compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:    
  # mssql:
  #   image: iws/mssql
  #   container_name: mssql-server    
  #   ports:
  #     - "1433:1433"

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:      
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
      - ./certs:/etc/nginx/certs

  myapp:
    image: iws/cestujnakole
    container_name: myapp          
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=cestujnakole.cz,www.cestujnakole.cz
    volumes: 
      - ./certs:/app/certs
      - ../myapp/wwwroot:/app/wwwroot
```

I have follow structure:

In my pc:

```
 - /Users/me/projects
   - nginx-proxy
     - docker-compose.yml
     - certs
       - myapp.pfs
       - myapp.key
       - etc.
   - myapp
     - out
     - Dockerfile
```

And in my VPS:

```
 - /var/www/projects
   - nginx-proxy
     - docker-compose.yml
     - certs
       - myapp.pfs
       - myapp.key
       - etc.
   - myapp
   - etc.
```

In my app, I need to read certs/myapp.pfs file. When file doesn't exist, application crash down.

To vps I load finished container (`docker save/load`)

**On localhost everything works file**, after run docker compose up, from nginx-proxy folder, but on remote server, I got this:

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate cestujnakole
Recreating cestujnakole
Attaching to cestujnakole
cestujnakole    | Running Environment: Production
cestujnakole    | 
cestujnakole    | Unhandled Exception: Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
cestujnakole    |    at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)
cestujnakole    |    at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.FromFile(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
cestujnakole    |    at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
cestujnakole    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.KestrelServerOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(KestrelServerOptions options, String fileName, String password)
cestujnakole    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsCache`1.CreateOptions()
cestujnakole    |    at System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore[T](T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory)
cestujnakole    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.KestrelServer..ctor(IOptions`1 options, IApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
cestujnakole    | --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
cestujnakole    |    at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
cestujnakole    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
cestujnakole    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScoped(ScopedCallSite scopedCallSite, ServiceProvider provider)
cestujnakole    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.<>c__DisplayClass16_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProvider provider)
cestujnakole    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
cestujnakole    |    at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
cestujnakole    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureServer()
cestujnakole    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
cestujnakole    |    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
cestujnakole    |    at CykloWeb.Program.Main(String[] args) in /Users/petrtomasek/projects/CykloWeb/Program.cs:line 22
cestujnakole exited with code 139
```

> No such file in app means, cert file doesn't exist in remote pc

When i drop from remote machine folders to mount, after compose-up are created. It is very interesting.

Here is `ls- l` commnad on my remote structure:

```
ls -l
total 16
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Jan 25 17:58 myapp
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Jan 20 13:02 mysql
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Jan 25 16:50 nginx-proxy
```

And nginx-proxy (my docker startup folder):

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Jan 25 18:03 certs
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  883 Jan 25 18:03 docker-compose.yml
```

I tested to nginx-proxy folder `chmod -R and 775`, after this 777, but nothing helped.

Where could the problem be?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: have you tried running it manually, whithout docker-compose, to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, I tested this. The same problem. I think, the problem is in permissions of remote folders, because in my mac I have it in home directory and works it well. And application self works on remote too.

Comment: Yes seems a problem about the file disk format when you try to access a certificate file from a different platform, like running a docker container in linux host on a shared windows disk. This was my case. I solved the problem by coping a old certificates created directly in the linux host (not windows shared) folder.

Comment: Please see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56824859/how-to-run-dockered-asp-net-core-app-generated-by-visual-studio-2019-on-linux-p