ASP .NET using SSL cert from outside its docker container
I am running an Ubuntu server with a docker container that contains my ASP .NET website. I was able to run it just fine before switching to using HTTPS but now when I run my container, I get the following errors.
app_1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
app_1  |       Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
app_1  | Unhandled exception. Interop+Crypto+OpenSslCryptographicException: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file
   at Interop.Crypto.CheckValidOpenSslHandle(SafeHandle handle)
   at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.OpenSslX509CertificateReader.FromFile(String fileName, SafePasswordHandle password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(String fileName, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(String fileName, String password)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ListenOptionsHttpsExtensions.UseHttps(ListenOptions listenOptions, String fileName, String password)

Now I assume the issue is my container is struggling to read the SSL cert due to it being located outside the container. I am assuming I am setting up the volume inside docker-compose wrong or something but I have been trying to fix it for a while, and I am not sure what the issue is exactly since the keys exist. I have also made lots of different SSL certs and have never had an issue with them before besides from the fact I switched to using ASP .NET over nginx to try it out.
:~# ls /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

Now here is my volume section inside of docker-compose.
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem:/etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.pem:ro
      - /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem:/etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem:ro

Now here is my CreateHostBuilder method inside my Program class.
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                    .UseKestrel(options =>
                    {
                        options.ListenAnyIP(80); // HTTP
                        options.ListenAnyIP(443, listenOptions =>
                        {
                            listenOptions.UseHttps("/etc/ssl/certs/fullchain.pem", "/etc/ssl/private/privkey.pem");
                        });
                    });
            });

I also tried changing the chmod to 644 for these files but that did not do anything either does anyone have any ideas what the issue could be?

Try configuring the key store as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-providers . Note the type of encryption used

@PolikarposGoldshtein Well yes there appears to be two problems firstly, is the key gen storage you pointed out however this was lessor concern compared to the other issue of my docker container not being able to read the SSL certs from the host. But I appreciate the link and will look into solving the warning do you have an idea on how to solve the main error aka the file not found error?

Check this link out. Important is to set certificate related environment variables for container: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md

@SlavaKuravsky I mean but that still does not explain why the file can't be found because I am not using user secrets as it is. If the current version is not working theres no point in adding complexity. I have tried using secrets in the past many times and none of my questions get answered. So, I rather focus on getting thing to at least work before going through the pain of using docker or user secrets.

Here you can see the steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58346414/3730077

I assume 'ls' output you shown is from inside the container?

Initial troubleshooting steps for identifying key-related issues inside containers:

From inside the container, can you cat the key and secret?
If your application is running as a user other than root, does that user have permission to cat the key/secret?
Also, does that user have permission to ls every parent directory the key is stored in?

If you can cat the key and ls the parent(s), your problem lies inside the application.
When dealing with letsencrypt certs, the two most common issues are permissions and symlinks. For permissions, the accessing user must have read permissions for the key, and execute permissions for all parent directories. Since letsencrypt often writes the key with root:root permissions, your containers may not be able to access them. setuid and setgid mappings, used to translate permissions from host into container, vary significantly between container implementations.
Also remember that the certificate you're linking to is technically a symlink, not a file. In many cases, symlinks are not correctly handled across abstraction layers. That's why it's important to try to cat the contents of the files themselves, to verify that they aren't simply "empty placeholders."
